# javafx setMouseTransparent(true) question

Tags: javafx

i set tip.setMouseTransparent(true);but tip still stop t1(TextField) click action, t2 is work well, So how can i fix it?
My environment:JDK:17  JAVAFX:17.0.2

```
  @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        VBox vBox = new VBox();

        TextField t1 = new TextField();
        t1.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            System.out.println("t1 clicked");
        });
        VBox v2 = new VBox();
        TextField t2 = new TextField();
        VBox tip = new VBox();
        tip.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
        tip.setPrefSize(100,200);
        tip.setMouseTransparent(true);
        tip.setTranslateX(80);
        tip.setTranslateY(-100);
        v2.getChildren().addAll(t2,tip);

        vBox.getChildren().addAll(t1,v2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox,400,300);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
```

[image]

Comment: What's the use case here? This just seems like bad layout practices.

Comment: Although v2 is in a VBox after t1, it has content in it (tip) which is negatively Y translated.  Even though tip is mouse transparent v2 is not.   So v2 is obscuring the t1 text box due to the overlapping bounds of its content, and intercepting mouse events.  You could make v2 mouse transparent, but then t2 would also be mouse transparent.  You can call v2.setViewOrder(1) so that t1 can receive mouse events rather than v2.  That renders t1 on top of all v2's content though and I don't know if that is what you want.  In all, I agree with @SedJ601.

Comment: I'm trying to create a validation component with JavaFX, where a bubble tip box appears in the top right corner when there's an error in the input. However, when this tip box appears, it ends up blocking the input box above it. Despite setting setMouseTransparent(true), it still doesn't work. @jewelsea

Comment: I'm trying to create a validation component with JavaFX, where a bubble tip box appears in the top right corner when there's an error in the input. However, when this tip box appears, it ends up blocking the input box above it. Despite setting setMouseTransparent(true), it still doesn't work @SedJ601

Comment: If it is a "tip box", perhaps a [`Tooltip`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html) would be more appropriate. –